# Something in the file is messing with ZSH

Tags: zsh, variable, variable-substitution

I have a file with such lines:

map_Kn Ellie_Caruncle_N.png

I'm trying to extract field #2, and use it twice in a command like this, but it's giving me some problems.

Here is a ZSH session:

```
~/Downloads/ellie $  cat onlyPNG.txt                                                                                                                                                      
map_Kd Ellie_HairBand_D.png
~/Downloads/ellie $  grep png onlyPNG.txt | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1 |  while read texture; do echo XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  $texture "https://example.com/resource/$i/Prev/$texture"; done
https://example.com/resource/30/Prev/Ellie_HairBand_D.png
```

Why is everything before XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX missing ? I understand it must have something to do with the two underscores in the filename, but I don't get it.

Comment: Remember that DOS text files have an extra carriage-return at the end of each line. When on Unix, this character causes the cursor to return to the start of the line when outputted. Just save your file as a Unix text file instead, if you're going to use it on Unix.  This has nothing to do with underscores.

Comment: That was sneaky... You are actually correct.

Comment: This _cause_ of the issue has many duplicates on this site, but I'm finding it difficult to locate one that is relevant to the specific issue (for flagging as duplicate). I'll get back to it later if nobody else finds one in the meanwhile.